# How can I know when or why the value of stage changes from 0 to 1 in the veins example?

Tags: omnet++, veins

When I run the example in veins 5.0, I know Multi stage can be defined by `numInitStages()` function. But I don't know when or why the value of stages changes from 0 to 1 in the `BaseModule.cc` files.

```
void BaseModule::initialize(int stage)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question here. Also, please, use tags relevant to the technologies you're using. For instance, programming language tag would be very useful here, as you'd attract more people relevant to your question and you wouldn't attract those, who aren't competent in the topic in question, and who have ignored particular tags to encounter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulation environment is responsible for calling subsequent stages during initialization.
For example, let's assume that one defines for a module:

```
int numInitStages() const { return 3; }
```

When the simulation is starting, the simulation environment calls:

```
initialize(0); 
initialize(1); 
initialize(2);
```

What is important: the simulation environment calls `initialize(0)` for *every* module, then it calls `initialize(1)` for *every* module whose `numInitStages()` returns 2 or more, then it calls `initialize(2)` for *every* module whose `numInitStages()` returns 3 or more, etc.
Thanks to this, we are sure that `initialize(1)` will be called *after* calling
`initialize(0)` in *all* modules. As a consequence, we may decide - for example - that an address is assigned in stage=1, and a socket that uses this address is opened in stage=2.

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:multi-stage-init)